# Change image source if file exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have http://jsfiddle.net/rcebw/3/

The point of this is I will have numerous of these `inlinediv` divs. Each one has 2 divs inside it, one which holds an image and one which holds a link. These are generated dynamically from a list of the subsites on another site.

What I want it to do is check each div with the class `inlinediv`. Get the inner text of the link in div `iconLinkText` and search for a file with that name at the site. (http://www.mojopin.co.uk/images/ for this test.) If it exists then change the image src to it.

I am probably taking the absolutely wrong route for this but I can't seem to get it to work. When testing it can't even find the `inlinediv` div! Says it's null.

I'm pretty new to jQuery but does anyone have any advice? (I don't even know if I've explained myself well!)

Comment: Your immediate problem is you're using Mootools on your fiddle. You need to select the version of jQuery you want to use from the Framework dropdown.

Comment: >:( Don't know why that changed. Cheers. I'll have more to work with now!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't have to use AJAX to do this, since you can hot-link images from other domains without any restrictions. Here's how you can check if an image exists:

```
function checkImage(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    // code to set the src on success
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    // doesn't exist or error loading
  };

  img.src = src; // fires off loading of image
}
```

Here's a working implementation http://jsfiddle.net/jeeah/

Comment: Really handy! Tho throws an "resource not found" error to the console.

Comment: Various other "Duplicate" answers from similar questions did not work as well for me as this one did.  Some AJAX driven approaches caused NS_ERROR_FAILURE's in Firefox, this one did not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modern Promise based way, which will return a Promise with a boolean value.

```js
function imageExists(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        resolve(true);
      }
      img.onerror = function (error) {
        resolve(false);
      }
      img.src = src;
    })
}


const imagePath = "http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif";
imageExists(imagePath).then(doesExist => {
  console.log('doesImageExist', doesExist);
});
```

You can of course use async/await syntax for this.

```
const doesImageExist = await imageExists(imagePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Same Origin Policy** prevents you from making AJAX requests to other domains. Unless you're running this on "http://www.mojopin.co.uk", this code won't work.

Comment: Ah right, well what would be the best way to check if a file exists? Also, it doesn't get past the fact that it can't seem to find `inlinediv`!

Comment: Insert an IMG tag and hook up an onload event. Then set the SRC of the image to the one you're testing. If it doesn't a show up in a few seconds, it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't understand, I want if the image doesn't exist to use the default image, but if it does exist to use it. I have got the rest of it working just need the check if exists.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this problem only with jQuery: The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) wont allow you to make requests to third web sites.

The easiest solution is to implement a service on your server that proxies the requests to the external website.

Basically if your website is on

http://www.foo.bar

then you create

http://www.foo.bar/scheckscript.php (for example)

that you can query with the url you need

http://www.foo.bar/scheckscript.php?url=http%3A//www.third.com