# Validate Image URL

Tags: javascript

I have a image URL (http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR_RHZrrb25Cx1qGPul6PYsCnVsIqtRuJxRS1Bj0I8DPXqQx-zow). I want to validate this in JavaScript whether image exists or not. Please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src ="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR_RHZrrb25Cx1qGPul6PYsCnVsIqtRuJxRS1Bj0I8DPXqQx-zowsd";

} catch(err)
{
    //
}

if(img.height > 0) {
 //image exists
} else {
 // image not exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load your image in an hidden DIV and check if the image was loaded.
I suggest you to use jQuery to achieve this.

Further reading on the load Event: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

HTML:

```
<div id="image-container" style="display: none">
    <img src="http://your/image/url">
</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery Code:

```
    $('img', '#image-container ').load(function() {
        // image loaded
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is almost  same as [Change image source if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678899/change-image-source-if-file-exists) which was previously posted by anothershrubery.

You can try this

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/image1.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://mydomain2.com/images/image1.jpg'" />
```

Alternatively

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!-
function testImage(URL) {
var tester=new Image();
tester.onLoad=isGood;
tester.onError=isBad;
tester.src=URL;
}

function isGood() {
alert('That image exists!');
}

function isBad() {
alert('That image does no exist!');
}
//--></script>
```