# Checking if image does exists using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if image exists with given url using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery)
>   [Change image source if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678899/change-image-source-if-file-exists)

I am throwing the value of an image path from a textbox into boxvalue and want to validate if the image exist using javascript.

```
 var boxvalue = $('#UrlQueueBox').val();
```

I browsed stackoverflow and found the below to get the image width/height, but don't want to use this.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid');
```

How can an I validate if it is really an image from the image path?

Comment: Look this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678899/change-image-source-if-file-exists

Comment: @FelipeOriani That is to create a new image.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I don't see any question marks in your post...

Comment: @maerics - How can an I validate if it is really an image from the image path?

Comment: To those who hit the close of the question, please read the question again.  I do not want to do it from #SelectorID but from the image path.

The question highlighted as duplicate is using the #SelectorID.

Comment: [You asked the same thing more than 2 years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery). What do you want to know now?

Comment: @vault Nice find.  But if you see closely it is still the image #selectorid not the direct image check.

Comment: Don't stop at first answer, [what about Helmut's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11775226/1521064)?

Comment: @vault That is ajax which I do not want.  maerics has already given the answer I require.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The general strategy is to use an [DOM `Image` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) instance, set the `src` property to the URL of the image you want to check (which will cause the browser to fetch and load the image), and then handle the `load` and `error` events to determine existence or absence, respectively.

Here's an example promise-based approach:

```javascript
function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var img = new Image()
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(true))
    img.addEventListener('error', () => resolve(false))
    img.src = url
  })
}

const url = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png'
imageExists(url)
  .then(ok => console.log(`RESULT: exists=${ok}`))
  //                    => RESULT: exists=true
```

Comment: This test creates a new image which is saved under Resources --> Images in the Google Chrome browser whether or not the url is a valid image or not which I don't particularly like.

Comment: This is great, but can you get it to return the URL?

I've got a loop that tries to load an icon for a list, and I need something that will return either the URL you tried, or a default URL if the image doesn't exist. All the solutions seem to run some code or dump to the console.

Comment: not an expert  but this still helped end of 2019 (vue/nuxt) thanks...

Comment: Nice that onerror is not an attribute, follows https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366589/458321 - The attribute is deprecated, not the event. Doesn't work in IE11 (for those who have to provide commercial support)

Answer (score 8):

You can create a function and check the `complete` property.

```
function ImageExists(selector) {
    var imageFound = $(selector); 

    if (!imageFound.get(0).complete) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (imageFound.height() === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and call this funciton

```
 var exists = ImageExists('#UrlQueueBox');
```

*Same function with the url instead of a selector as parameter (your case):*

```
function imageExists(url){

    var image = new Image();

    image.src = url;

    if (!image.complete) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (image.height === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can it be done without the #selector or #Id.  I want it directly from the path.

Comment: will that work in all browser, because that will work, if the image that already loaded is cached. and so the creation of a new image, will just load the already cached one. But if that process failed, then it will fail, it's the case when the cache is disabled. Still a good function though.