# How to check whether image is loaded or not loaded from the mentioned URL

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-web-services

```
var image = new Image();

image.onLoad = function() {
  alert("loaded");
}

image.onError = function() {
  alert("not loaded");
};

image.src ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/profileImages.mySample.com/spiderman.png" //dummy URL for reference only.
```

This is my code.
I am fetching my images from amazon services, problem is that if I am getting some error like:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>ABCDEFGHIJ</RequestId>
<HostId>
AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
</HostId>
</Error>
```

then my code is not executing the image.onError().

how to check whether image exist at the URL ?

Comment: I think this [link][1] might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript

Comment: The S3 hosting may not be configured for public access ?? Can you simply download the image via its url from the browser ?

Comment: @sanket: yes able to get the image in browser. earlier making some other mistake.

Comment: I'm assuming you've realised that there is a big difference between `onerror` and `onError` ? The former will work, where-as the latter wont -- at least for modern browsers.

Comment: @pebbl: yes i got that... struggled for almost an hour to make it work, finally got it working after replacing just "E" with "e"...

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zd2vj/1/)

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
  alert("loaded");
}

image.onerror = function() {
  alert("not loaded");
};

image.src ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/profileImages.mySample.com/spiderman.png";
```