# Check whether file exists with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How check if file (image) exists in javascript using jquery

```
img = 'someimage.jpg'
$('<img>').attr('src',img);
```

Comment: I found 14 similar threads using your search term. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript

Comment: You can take a look here: https://gist.github.com/vdite/11369781 . An other idea is this: `<img src="image.gif" onerror="imgError()" />` I have this from the link Tom Walters told.

Answer (score 2):

Attach an  onerror event listener to that image.

```
img.onerror = function(){ alert("not found"); }
```

or use get request

```
$.get('someimage.jpg', function(data){ 

}).fail(function() {
    alert('not found'); 
});
```