# javascript checking if file exists with google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, file-exists

I am trying to check and see if an image exists so I can adjust my contentString accordingly. However, when I try to do this, only one pin shows up on the map (the first one).

```
  var checkins = <?php echo $json; ?>;
  function imageExists(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
    img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
    img.src = url;
  }
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795}
    });
    setMarkers(map);
  }
  function setMarkers(map) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < checkins.length; i++) {
      var checkin = checkins[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: parseFloat(checkin[2]), lng: parseFloat(checkin[3])},
        map: map,
        title: checkin[1]
      });
      var imageUrl = 'http://rjbogz.ddns.net/pictures/'+checkin[0]+'.jpg';
      imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
        if (exists){
          contentString = '<b>'+checkin[6]+'</b><br><b>'+checkin[4]+'</b> by <b>'+checkin[5]+'</b><br>At <b>'+checkin[1]+'</b><br><img src="pictures/'+checkin[0]+'.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px;">';
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString);
        } else {
          contentString = '<b>'+checkin[6]+'</b><br><b>'+checkin[4]+'</b> by <b>'+checkin[5]+'</b><br>At <b>'+checkin[1]+'</b>';
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, description) {
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(description);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
  }
```

As you can see by the `imageExists` function, I tried adding a check to see if the image exists, but then it only plots one pin on the map. The website is currently published to http://rjbogz.ddns.net/map.php if you want to take a look at what it looks like. An example of what I want to fix would be if you click on the icon in Bermuda (there is no image file associated with it).

Comment: What javascript errors do you see in the console?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I do not get any errors in the javascript unfortunately. It is just not displaying correctly. Above is the code that works (what is currently on the website) and the two pieces below are what I replace and what I replace it with, respectively, to make it only put the first pin.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue, including any required data/HTML/CSS.

Comment: Have you got something in a JS Fiddle?  Your domain is not accessible where I am.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The code contains a bit of php which is required to allow it to run. I haven't quite figured out jsfiddle to work with that.

Comment: Just take the generated HTML and JS and place it in the fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ts9udgn7/1/

Comment: @user1911612 Your code to check the image only work when the image has already been downloaded/failed before calling the function `ImageExist`, `img.height` will always be 0 at the first call because the image has not been downloaded yet. you should see this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript .

Comment: @Hacketo thanks for the info. I took a look at the thread, but I might be doing something wrong. I have the images local on my webserver too, if that makes a difference. I have updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: @user1911612 as `imageExists` is now a function that use async callback to check if the image exists, you need to call `bindInfoWindow` at the end of the `imageExists` callback. because atm `bindInfoWindow` is called before `contentString` is filled.

Comment: @Hacketo Well silly me. That's all good now and all the plots are there, however, the whole `addListener('click') function doesn't seem to be working. I updated the code above again. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @user1911612 I tried and it seem work.

Comment: @Hacketo I just published the site to the link above. You can see there that when you click the pins, the info window doesn't show up. Where are you trying it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104566/discussion-between-hacketo-and-user1911612).

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, there's just a couple issues with `if (ImageExists(image) != 0) {`

First, you've declared the function as `ImageExist`, so you'd need to fix that typo.  Second, you probably want to change `if(ImageExists(image) != 0) {` to `if(ImageExists(image)) {` since your function is going to return a boolean value.

And finally, you've got some unclosed HTML in your `contentString`.

Making those adjustments to your code should fix it, it would look something like this:

```
if (ImageExist(image)) {
    contentString = '<b>'+checkin[6]+'</b><br><b>'+checkin[4]+'</b> by <b>'+checkin[5]+'</b><br>At <b>'+checkin[1]+'</b><br><img src="pictures/'+checkin[0]+'.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px;">';
} else {
    contentString = '<b>'+checkin[6]+'</b><br><b>'+checkin[4]+'</b> by <b>'+checkin[5]+'</b><br>At <b>'+checkin[1]+'</b>';
}
```

You can see it working in the JS Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/ts9udgn7/4/

And an updated fiddle that shows it working with images from placehold.it:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/ts9udgn7/6/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Had to be something silly, of course.

Comment: Okay, so I implemented this, and it worked, but now it just stopped working. Even in your jsfiddle. Any ideas there? The `ImageExists()` function seems to always be returning false now.

Comment: It looks like its still working in the fiddle.  The `ImageExists()` function has always return false in the JS Fiddle for me, because your domain is blocked by my ISP.  If I use images from placehold.it, using the data from your array as image sizes, it works.  I updated the fiddle to show that: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/ts9udgn7/6/

Comment: I see your updated code, but it is still only making it into the else statement for me. I am not sure why. http://i.imgur.com/ml1cKmi.png

Comment: @AdamKonieska this work only because your browser already downloaded the image, ImageExist will always return false for new images.