# Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken

Tags: javascript, angular

I am fetching a large number of image URLs from an API and display them in a angular 2 web application. Some of the URLs are broken and i want to replace them with a default picture that is stored locally on my webserver. Does anyone have a suggestion how to test the urls and in the case of status code 404 replace the broken image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Listen to the `error` event of the image element:

```ts
<img [src]="someUrl" (error)="updateUrl($event)">
```

where `updateUrl(event) { ... }` assigns a new value to `this.someUrl`.

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ztjpm?p=preview)

If you want to check in code only you can use the method explained in [Checking if image does exists using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript)

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'img[default]',
  host: {
    '(error)':'updateUrl()',
    '[src]':'src'
   }
})
class DefaultImage {
  @Input() src:string;
  @Input() default:string;

  updateUrl() {
    this.src = this.default;
  }
}
```

[Directive Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZOQirM?p=preview)

Comment: Why is this down voted?  AFAIK this is the correct method, leveraging the browsers events...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer would it be good to have directive in place to handle such thing..? any thoughts? +1

Comment: You're right. I somehow missed the "default picture" and assumed some calculation to get an alternative URL.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to specify the default image in the directive as a class property instead? If I miss a `[default]='...'` in the image I would be skipping it and you avoid adding `default` in every <img> tag.

Comment: That was the intention that the directive is only applied when a `default="xxx"` is provided. If someone wants different behavior it should be easy to customize. Not sure what you mean by "specify the default image in the directive as a class property instead". Class property on the parent component? That should work by using `[default]="somePropertyProvidingTheDefaultPath"`.

Comment: Great answer! any ideas on how to do this with Ionic2's 'ion-img' html element?

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg sorry, I don't know Ionic.

Comment: Thank you, it just solved a IIS relative path problem with images for me. U da boss!

Comment: `/* Angular 11 */
@Directive({
    selector: 'img[default]',
})
export class DefaultImageDirective {
    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Input() default = 'assets/placeholder.png';

    @HostListener('error') onError(): void {
     
        this.elem.nativeElement.src = this.default;
    }
}`

Answer (score 56):

You can use **`onError`** event this way to handle **`invalid url`** or **`broken url`**.

- https://plnkr.co/edit/fD8zxd?p=preview

```
<img [src]="invalidPath" onError="this.src='images/angular.png'"/>
```

**This way you can directly assign img path to src with onError event**

Comment: @Gunter's answer is correct I think, and looks `Angular2` way by having `()` for calling events..

Comment: check the plunker at least. Its I think not about being correct or not correct . It about having some other ways....what you say?

Comment: don't take it wrong way dude.. I meant to say its just slight change in his way.. I do appreciate your efforts too +1.

Comment: No. I'm not taking it wrong way dont worry. Just saying there can be some other options too. This is one of them. This way you can directly assign path.

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar

Comment: nice micronyks, but it's not working, please can you tell me what m doing wrong <img src="https://in.bmscdn.com/iedb/movies/images/website/poster/large/{{item.$key}}.jpg" 
                                        title="album-name" class="img-responsive" onError="this.src=''" alt=" ">

Comment: It's a little off topic...can anybody explain the difference between (error) and onError? They are not the same.

Comment: Works fine on Angular 6

Comment: Works for me on Angular 8 & 9. Thanks @micronyks. 

Comment: don't work on angular latest version , getting error its not known property of img

Answer (score 28):

My example on angular 4

```
<img [src]="img" (error)="img.src = errorImg" #img>
```

1. Where img - path to image;
2. error - error emmit
3. errorImg - path to default img
4. #img - link to img object

Comment: its the cleanest way to do it, works without any issue

Comment: How do you make the #img link (as well as the img reference in the error handler) dynamic in the case where you have the image tag in an ngFor?

Answer (score 8):

I use a base64 loading spinner:

```
<img [src]="photoContainer.photo.url | secure" onError="this.src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'">
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a very simple solution that worked for me. This doesn't check for 404's however I had objects that possibly had and .image attribute. I know this isn't the answer to his question but hopefully it helps some one out there.

```
<img class="list-thumb-img" [attr.src]="item.image?.url ? item.image.url : 'assets/img/140-100.png'">
```

Comment: Yes. its the Simplest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A perfect Angular 8 directive:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appImage]'
})
export class ImageDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() src;

    constructor(private imageRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
            this.setImage(this.src);
        };

        img.onerror = () => {
            // Set a placeholder image 
            this.setImage('assets/placeholder.png');
        };

        img.src = this.src;
    }

    private setImage(src: string) {
        this.imageRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', src);
    }
}
```

Now, HTML will be:

```
<img [src]="'/some/valid-image.png'" appImage>
```

Comment: it's not applying directive. I created directive and not worked!!

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to change an image that is not loading or the source is broken...
Angular 8, just have to change the src of this target for a default asset:**

- Component HTML

  > <... [src]="person.pictureUrl" (error)="pictNotLoading($event)" >
- Component TS

  > pictNotLoading(event) { 
  >       event.target.src = 'assets/nopicture.png';
  >   }

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution for fallback on multi images.
we basically detach the ChangeDetector once we resolve the image so we can reduce CPU on vm check cycles once image is resolved.

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppStore} from "angular2-redux-util/dist/index";



@Component({
    selector: 'logoCompany',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
    template: `
            <div style="padding-top: 7px" > 
              <span style="color: gainsboro; font-family: Roboto">{{getBusinessInfo('companyName')}}</span>
              <!--<img style="width: 35px" class="img-circle" src="http://galaxy.example.me/Resources/Resellers/{{getBusinessInfo('businessId')}}/{{getBusinessInfo('fileName')}}" />-->
              <img style="width: 35px" class="img-circle" [src]="getImageUrl()" (load)="onImageLoaded()" (error)="onImageError()" />
            </div>
    `
})

export class LogoCompany {

    constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {    
    }
    private imageRetries:number = 0;
    private unsub;


    private detach() {
        this.cdr.detach();
    }

    private getImageUrl() {          
        var url = '';
        switch (this.imageRetries){
            case 0: {
                url = 'http://galaxy.example.me/Resources/Resellers/' + this.getBusinessInfo('businessId') + '/Logo.jpg'
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                url = 'http://galaxy.example.me/Resources/Resellers/' + this.getBusinessInfo('businessId') + '/Logo.png'
                break;
            }
            default: {
                url = 'assets/person.png'
                break;
            }

        }
        return url;
    }

    private onImageLoaded() {
        this.detach();
    }

    private onImageError() {
        this.imageRetries++;
    }

    private getBusinessInfo(field):string {
          return '12345';
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event of error happen only if the url is not correct,
if the url is correct but the file is not exists you can use in this code

[javascript check if file exists on server:](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/check+file+exist+in+href+angular)

(Note that the 404 is a number and not a string)

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
xhr.send();
 
if (xhr.status == 404) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `(error)` event of the image element & if image is broken you can hide the image itself:

```
<img #image src="..." (error)="image.hidden = true" [hidden]="image.hidden">
```

Or any other element:

```
<div [hidden]="image.hidden"></div>
```

Or completely remove any div:

```
<div *ngIf="!image.hidden"></div>
```

Or when using *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let some of somethings">
   <div *ngIf="some.imageUrl" class="image-class-1 img-class-2">
     <img src="{{some.imageUrl}}" (error)="some.imageUrl = null"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a ternary operator for this use case.
I am assuming that you are getting the responses from a remote server

```
<img src="{{ res.image ? res.image : onErrorFunction() }}"
```

If you don't want to have the image from server write the path in single quotes ''.

Here if the link is broken then it will go to onErrorFunction if it isn't broken the res.image will be loaded.