# Detect request errors in Angular 2 Property bindings that make http requests

Tags: angular

Is there a way to detect a request error in Angular 2 property bindings that make Http requests, like [link] and [src].

My situation is I have an object with

```
{
  local: '/images/abc.jpg',
  remote: 'http://linkToImage.jpg'
}
```

And the template

```
<img [src]="local">
```

So I'm trying to point to `remote` when `local` returns a `404` or request error.

Comment: Got around it thanks to @amit-suhag, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this work or not but can you try doing this with ternary operators

```
<img src="{{enquiry.buyer_email ? '/images/ico_yes.png' : '/images/ico_no.png'}}">
```

Or something like this with binary operators:

```
<img src="{{enquiry.buyer_email && '/images/ico_yes.png' || '/images/ico_no.png'}}">
```

replace values with remote and local

Comment: ternary operator will look for a falsy value. In this case, the value is not falsy, it is defined. The only difference is that it is a path that returns a 404 not found when called via http.

Comment: Listen to the error event of the image element: <img [src]="someUrl" (error)="updateUrl($event)">.. check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken