# angular2 onError image binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wondering if we can bind or interpolate the onError on the image tag using angular2,

on the app.component.ts:

```
imageUrl:string;

  constructor( ) {
      this.imageUrl = 'graphics/placeholder.gif';
   }
```

on the app.component.html:

```
<img class="img-responsive" [src]="'graphics/image-1.jpg'" onError="imageUrl"/>
```

The method below works.

```
<img class="img-responsive" [src]="'graphics/image-1.jpg'" onError="this.src='graphics/placeholder.gif'"/>
```

But as we using a many images on the app and I would like to make it a simple dynamic solution, I found this answer as well,

[Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken)

but for some reason is not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It was almost complete he just forgot to change the image after the event.

```
errorHandler(event) {
   console.debug(event);
   event.target.src = "https://cdn.browshot.com/static/images/not-found.png";
}
```

Here is the
[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDtg5mcBUJMCeIu8cPQ8?p=preview)

Answer (score 25):

component.ts

```
onImgError(event){
 event.target.src = './assets/imgs/altImg.png'
//Do other stuff with the event.target
}
```

component.html

```
 <img [src]="imgUrl" (error)="onImgError($event)">
```