# Vuejs - Check if image url is valid or broken

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

It's exactly same as [Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken).

how can I implement this in vuejs?

Comment: The same way: onerror event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when an image fails to load in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript)

Answer (score 46):

Vue.js has an `@error` event that you can hook into. From vuejs [issue#3261](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3261#issuecomment-231933953). So you could do:

```
<template>
   <img :src="avatarUrl" @error="imageLoadError" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    imageLoadError () {
      console.log('Image failed to load');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Edit**: I've discovered this also works for `<audio>` tags (and I suspect other elements which define a `src` attribute and load an asset)!

**Edit2**: Silly me! It's actually an interface for adding a listener to the native [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors) event that many HTML elements emit, similar to `<input @blur="someHandler">`, etc.

Comment: I couldn't find any detailed information about `@error` in the documentations of Vue

Comment: @Asqan `onerror` is a valid HTML event that the `<img>` element can emit, so `@error` (or `v-on:error`) is just Vue's syntatic sugar to handle that `onerror` event. It's the same as calling `<button @click="clickHandler">`, `<input @blur="blurHandler">` or any other event listener for a valid HTML event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors

Answer (score 24):

It seems that @error works fine. I personally used a method with an event in order to set an alternative image.

```
<img :src="imageUrl" @error="imageUrlAlt">
```

The method:

```
imageUrlAlt(event) {
    event.target.src = "alt-image.jpg"
}
```

From Vue.js [issue#5404](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5404).

**Optimal solution**:

```
<img :src="imageUrl" @error="imageUrl='alt-image.jpg'">
```

Thanks everyone for your valuable comments.

Comment: I quite like this answer. It can be made completely inline without much mess, too.       

`<img :src="viewModel.logo" @error="$event.target.src = '[source image]'"
              alt="Company logo"
            />`

Comment: The more Vue approach would be to set a new value for `image` in the `imageUrlAlt` handler: `this.image = 'alt-image.jpg'`, having Vue update the DOM instead of us manually touching it.

Answer (score 1):

I use a computed property that returns a string with the placeholder URL instead of @error handler like this. This way if source is null or undefined the placeholder will be loaded.

```
<img :src="source || computedPropertyString" />
```

Comment: This won't work for cases where the `source` is defined but the image doesn't exist on that url (404) or is inaccessible (403).