# validate HTML in angular

Tags: angular, xss

How can I validate a valid looking html like below while validating html content received from a user/service. $sanitize does not seem to identify it.

For example,

```
<img src='image' onError='alert()' />
```

How can I also remove some of the invalud HTML like alert()? Or does $sanitize treat these kind of blocks as valid HTML?

TIA

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430121/5468463

Comment: So, $sanitize will not remove script code like alert()?  Should these be handled separately?