# How to properly load and bind a parameter to a img url using Ionic 3 / Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm loading an image from a S3 bucket in my Ionic view like this:

```
<ion-avatar>
  <img class="circle" src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/cp{{client?.id}}.jpg">
</ion-avatar>
```

The image name I want to load is "cp1.jpg", and the client?.id value 1 is taken from the component script:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  let email = this.storage.getLocalUser().email;
  this.clientService.findByEmail(email)
    .subscribe(resp => {
      this.client = resp;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I'm also using the "?" operator in client?.id because if I don't, I get an "id undefined" error and the page doesn't even load.

However, I'm getting a canceled request on my Network inspector, which is trying to retrieve the image before the "1" value is concatenated in the image name:

[image]

Right after that error, the "1" value is provided to the view and the image is loaded. But I'd like to not get that undesired retrieving try.

How can I properly load and bind the client id to get the image name right, and also to avoid getting that canceled request error?

Comment: You could just have `*ngIf="client?.id"`

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<ion-avatar>
  <img class="circle" [src]="avatar_for_client()">
</ion-avatar>
```

In your `.ts`:

```
avatar_for_client(){
  if (this.client){
    return `https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/cp${this.client.id}.jpg`
  }else{
    return <some placeholder image url>
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be `avatar_for_client()`?

Comment: Worked thanks! Another little fix: ${this.client.id}. By the way, how would I also return the placeholder image url if the bucket image doesn't exist? Thank you.

Comment: @NelioAlves you can listen to the `(error)` event https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430121/2697183