# ng-src and ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Lets say i take some photo in according to id of something and put it in an array like:

```js
data.attributes.photos = [ "12.jpg", "12_1.jpg", "12_2.jpg" , 12_3.jpg, ... ]
```

and use it with ngFor like :

```js
<ngb-carousel>
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photos">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
```

now there is something called *ng-src* and *on-error* in Angular which shows a sample image when there is no any image given in the array.

like this :

```js
 <ngb-carousel>
                            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photo">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" ng-src={{photo}}}  err-SRC="http://google.com/favicon.ico" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
                            </ng-template>
                        </ngb-carousel>
```

It may work but since i dont know the number of images. is it possible to not show the image if it does not exist in the url of my src?

Comment: Seems you're mixing up Angular.js and Angular. The former is Angular-only, the later is Angular.js-only.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken/36430121#36430121

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<img [src]="someUrl" (error)="updateUrl($event)">
```

to check if loading `someUrl` causes an error and then for example update `someUrl` to load some alternative image instead.

See [Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken/36430121#36430121) for an example.