# How check with Angular 8 unit test if image exists in given path?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a picture in `assets/logo.png` and i wanna check inside the .spec.ts if this picture exists and if not throw error (to be truthy or not). How can i implement something like this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken)

Comment: I use angular 8 and i wanna write unit test - Not checking inside the component.ts file :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try below code:

```
    it('should set image logo path as expected', () => {
        const ele = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img');
        expect(ele[0]['src']).toContain('logo.png'); // if you dont have `id` in `img` , you need to provide index as `ele[index]`
        // OR use 
       const ele1 = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#img-id");
       expect(ele1['src']).toContain('logo.png');
    });
```

It checks if below image is present in `src` attribute.  You can be more specific by using `.toEqual('assets/logo.png')`

Answer (score 2):

create a html for image , assign the image path to source and check if the image tag has height and width of the assigned image

```
it('should set image logo path as expected', () => {
  let ele = document.createElement("img"); 
  ele.id = 'eee'; 
  ele.src = this.source; 
  setTimeout(() => { 
     expect(ele.height).toBeGreaterThan(0);
     expect(ele.width).toBeGreaterThan(0);
   }, 5000);
 });
```

if the image path is not correct the width and height of `ele` will be 0.

Comment: This test will always pass. You need to use `doneFn`. I also would recommend to create all elements in a `beforeAll` loop, if possible, so you only have to wait once.

Answer (score 0):

Since I also had to test if 'my-image.png' is not only correctly referred to but also really displayed, I elaborated a bit on Shlok Nangia's answer and came up with the following snippet, which works for me (the else-part is actually not needed):

```
it('should display my-image.png', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const imgElement = compiled.querySelector('img.my-class');
    if (imgElement) {
        const rectangle = imgElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(rectangle.height).toBeGreaterThan(0);
            expect(rectangle.width).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        window.alert('should display my-image.png: failed');
    }
});
```