# Angular - Use a default image if image does not exist on server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image, rxjs

I have a component that will display a cover image. The user can upload a cover image and the component will display the user uploaded image. If the user doesn't upload an image, then I want to display a default image.

If there is no user uploaded image I want to return an error and call the changeSource(event), which should in theory bind a new image url to the img src. However I'm getting undefined for the event.target.src and I'm seeing a blank space where the default image should be. It works fine when displaying the custom image.

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let coverPhoto of coverPhotos">
    <img src="{{coverPhoto}}"
         (error) ="changeSource($event)" />
</div>
```

component.ts

```
this.myService.getPhotos(ImageType.Cover, this.id).subscribe(result => {
            this.coverPhotos = result;
        }, error => {
                this.errors = error;
                this.changeSource(event);
           }, () => {
        }
        );

changeSource(event) {      
        event.target.src = "https://imageurl";
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken)

Comment: Thanks. I've looked through this page already and created a directive, which didn't solve the issue either. Will look through it again though.

Comment: I wonder if it's a binding issue - try `<img [src]="coverPhoto" (error) ="changeSource($event)" />`

Comment: Thought it might be and tried that before but it throws an error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

directly use (where defaultImage is a variable in ts file which holds the default image path) -

```
(error)="$event.target.src = defaultImage"
```

your HTML -

```
<div *ngFor="let coverPhoto of coverPhotos">
  <img src="{{ coverPhoto }}" (error)="$event.target.src = defaultImage" />
</div>
```

[Working example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxanlf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You are passing event from this code in ts, which is obviously undefined, and you don't need to call this function from here -

```
this.myService.getPhotos(ImageType.Cover, this.id).subscribe(result => {
            this.coverPhotos = result;
        }, error => {
                this.errors = error;
                this.changeSource(event);
           }, () => {
        }
        );
```

Comment: I would contend that it's almost always a bad idea to manipulate the DOM directly in such a way in an Angular app. It would be better to swap out the binding in src than to get src out of sync with what Angular thinks it's bound to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on removing changeSource() function, however it still isn't working with (error)="$event.target.src = defaultImage". I'll keep on mining it and post a solution hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

The *ngFor was throwing it off. Removing this seemed to solve the problem. Not quite sure why so will post an edit when I discover why.

```
<div>
    <img src="{{coverPhotos}}"
         (error)="$event.target.src = defaultImage" />
</div>
```

Comment: That probably means `coverPhotos` isn't an array. ngFor is meant to loop over an array of items.