# Angular2 all image loaded

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-directive

I'm trying to figure out how should I detect if all image has been loaded in my element. 
My element is like this now:

```
<div class="flexbox" appMyMasonry>
    <div *ngFor="let new of specificNews | async}" class="box">

               <md-card class="example-card">
                   <img md-card-image src="{{new.coverImageUrl}}">
                   ....
```

appMyMasonry is a directive of mine: it makes an order/positioning based on how the elements should fill the available space... the important thing here is, that right now it works only if I call a method of the directory like this:

```
@ViewChild(MyMasonryDirective) directive = null

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.directive.sortElements();
  }
```

basically it works... but because of the ngAfterViewChecked() it call the function all the time.. one after an other and I hope there is a better way than just call it 10times in every second..
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the error event of the image element:

```
<img [src]="someUrl" (error)="doSomething($event)">
```

where doSomething(event) { ... } provide your manipulation with size or what you want.

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ztjpm?p=preview)

If you want to check in code only you can use the method explained in [Checking if image does exist using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript)

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'img[default]',
  host: {
    '(error)':'updateUrl()',
    '[src]':'src'
   }
})
class DefaultImage {
  @Input() src:string;
  @Input() default:string;

  updateUrl() {
    this.src = this.default;
  }
}
```

[Directive Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZOQirM?p=preview)

Comment: thanks, but it is not the solution for me... I'll catch the (load) event in the *grandparent's* directive :)