# how can i check if image exists in assets folder using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to check if a image exists in the folder using Angular 4.I have a list of image name that is returned from the server. What I need is to check if that image exists in the asset folder. Any help or idea would be great.

Comment: name are same or different names??

Comment: what do u mean? i need to check if the image exists in the folder by name

Comment: Is it relative or absolute path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this. Answer found on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651964/4700863)

```
// The "callback" argument is called with either true or false
// depending on whether the image at "url" exists or not.
function imageExists(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
  img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
  img.src = url;
}

// Sample usage
var imageUrl = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png';
imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
  console.log('RESULT: url=' + imageUrl + ', exists=' + exists);
});
```

I would like to warn you. Becareful with it, It can run you to performance issue for checking more images at once due to it's loading images to memory if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageExists(itemId) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = 'assets/menu_image/'+itemId+'.jpg';
    if (img.complete){
        return 'assets/menu_image/'+itemId+'.jpg'
    }else {
        return 'assets/logo-white.png'
    }
}
```