# Dynamic file type in image source

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a case where I have an image file inside `assets` directory. I know the filename at runtime but I don't know what's its type upfront. It can be: `logo.png`, `logo.svg` or `logo.jpeg`. I know I can check if given file exists (see: [how can i check if image exists in assets folder using angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282727/how-can-i-check-if-image-exists-in-assets-folder-using-angular-4)) but it can affect application`s performance. Is there a better way to create source to the image?

Comment: WHat is your purpose ? Giving context would greatly help.

Comment: It's prettye simple. Image file is uploaded by user to the server (outside of my Angular app) and then pushed by backend service into dist folder (into assets directory). It can have three formats (png, svg, jpeg) so I'm wondering how to create some kind of 'universal' src path for it. I'm looking for most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Then why don't you save the extension when you store it in your database ?

Comment: I'd very like to to that but unfortunately for some unrelated reasons it's not possible in this case.

Comment: Then your only solution is the one you found ... On the client side, in a web application, you can't read a folder, only a server can (from my personal knowledge of course). And don't worry about performance issues, if you try to load 4 images, it won't crash your app :)