# Render null if <img /> src url is 404

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I use react for an SPA

I have this `<img />` component

I pull the src from a URL that is created via props of the functional component that renders the `<img />`

Sometimes the URL works sometimes it returns a 404 but the img tag I still rendered and with the default .. missing image icon ...

HOW can I make it not render or render some random transparent img IF the first  URL is not valid (404)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript relevant maybe

Comment: Can u post img component?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. I found it very useful...

Answer (score 3):

As @Sterling Archer mentioned, your problem is relevant with [Checking if image does exists using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript) .

To sum it up, that is listening on img's onerror event, and once your url returns 404, `onerror` will be triggered.

```
const onError = () => {
    this.setState({ urlError: true })
}

render() {
    return (this.state.urlError ? <img onerror={this.onError} /> : null)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do a cors xhttp request to determine If the status is 404 and then set a state boolean. Use this bool to choose wether to render the image or return null