# ionic - check image url using JavaScript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a long list of images and I want to check each image (if broken, it should return false; else, return true)

I wrote this code but the function of checking the urls always return me wrong results

```
 ...
 validImages=[];
 this.list.forEach(item=>{
    if(checkImage(item.url)){
       validImages.push(item);
    }
 });
 ...
 checkImage(url){
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    console.log(image.onerror);
    if(image.onerror){return false;}else{return true;}
 }
```

hint: I could find these two statements. It works but i couldn't run them in my function to return true/false value

```
    image.onerror = function (evt){alert("can't download")};
    image.onload = function (evt){alert("can be download")};
```

So any helps for this issue ?

**EDIT**

Here is my new code

```
...
validImages=[];
this.list.forEach(item=>{
   this.imageExists(item.img, function(exists){
      if(exists){ // exists get correct true/false values
          validImages.push(item); //push function not works
      }
   });
});

checkImage(url, callback){
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onerror = function (evt){callback(false);};
    image.onload = function (evt){callback(true);};
}
```

Comment: Are Image URL HTTP requests?

Comment: yes, such as "https://****.image1.jpg"

Comment: You can just make a request for same, you will get 200 else error. Can't you check success and error in the same way?

Comment: Doing a network call for each url would be extremely slow and inefficient

Comment: @AliAbdulaal, can try answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript. May help you doing the same thing given in hints.

Comment: thanks @PradnyaSinalkar, I changed my code such as the answer but I got this errer "cannot read property 'validImages' of undefined "

Comment: You can share updated code to resolve an error.

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar I did, You can check the edit

Comment: Declare as validImages: Array<any> = [];