# calling function from rowcallback function datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. get all `img` tags from a certain `td` cell.
2. loop through `img` collection: check if image `loads(exists)` or not.
3. if image doesn't exists, set the image's `src` attribute to `default` src.

The script:

```
var default_img = "{{URL::to('/images/default-product-img.jpg')}}";
.
.
.

            fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {                
                var s_images = $(nRow).find('td:eq(1) img');
                var m_images = $(nRow).find('td:eq(2) img');
                var u_images = $(nRow).find('td:eq(3) img');

                s_images.each(function(index, element) {
                    let url = $(this).attr('src');
                    imageExists(url, function(exists) {
                        if(!exists) {
                            $(this).attr({'src': default_img, 'data-exists': exists});
                        }
                    });
                });                  
            },
```

The function from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript#answer-14651964):

```
   function imageExists(url, callback) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
      img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
      img.src = url;
    }
```

But images are still not loading, not even the default ones. Neither the `data-exists` attribute is set which I've added for test purpose.

e.g `url` that I am working with is :

```
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0020/4433/0057/products/0fc643cb997ee029b87b72ea84b2f9c6.jpg?v=1542290204
```

JSFiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/3smx18o6/1/`

What am I missing here? How should the functions be called from the `callback` function?

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is inside your callback

Comment: Quick fix is store reference to `this` inside the `each` and before entering  ` imageExists(url, function(exists) ` and use that reference inside the callback