# Check whether an image exists, if not set a default image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, image

I have a lot of images. like:

```
<img src="src1"/>
<img src="src2"/>
<img src="src3"/>
```

Some of the image maybe do not exist. So the browser will show a broken image picture. It is ugly. How to use Javascript not jQuery to determine whether an image exists? If not, give a local image to replace it. Thank you.

I tried the code , it replaced all the images not only those not exist.

```
function imgError(image) {
            image.onerror = "";
            image.src = "http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/85/69/99_avatar_middle.jpg?random=10.20420048222877085";
            return true;
        }

        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i].onerror=imgError(imgs[i]);
        }
```

the images are

```
<img src="rrrrr"  />
    <img src="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"/>
```

the first picture does not exist , the second one exists. when I run it in chrome , all the picture were replaced...

Comment: There is an answer already here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/4813913

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678899/change-image-source-if-file-exists, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651348/checking-if-image-does-exists-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: I tried those code ,but it replace all the image not those not exists.function imgError(image) {
                image.onerror = "";
                image.src = "http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/85/69/99_avatar_middle.jpg?random=10.20420048222877085";
                return true;
            }
        
            <!-- 把图片src改为正确的src -->
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
                imgs[i].onerror=imgError(imgs[i]);
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using this code:

```
function nofind() {
    var img = event.srcElement
    img.src="http://www.cnblogs.com/sys/common/image/fileoperation/icon/default.gif";
    img.onerror = null; 
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onError=nofind;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Simple solution:

```
<img src="http://src1/img.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://src1/error-img.jpg';">
```

Set within the `img` tag

**Update**

A better solution which stops infinite loops - thanks @stom

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src = 'error.jpg';">
```

[Originally posted by @svend here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid/980948#980948)

Comment: Yes ,But I want to use it to all the images, you can look the problem again , I tried the method in others problems , it replaced all the image  not only those do not exist

Comment: Simply add `onerror="this.src='http://src1/error-img.jpg';"` to all your image tags, then any which fail will show your error default image

Comment: This is easy solution , but if `error-img.jpg` does not exist, this causes an infinite loop, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/980948/2218697) answer.

Comment: The link of originally posted has the best solution which is by CSS only. No need for any JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind onerror event listener to all the images in the DOM..